# Is there exist postive integer $x,y,z,w,n$ and $k$ such $x^{n},y^{n+k},z^{n+3k},w^{n+5k}$ be geometric sequence

Tags: number-theory

Is there exist postive integer  $x,y,z,w,n$ and $k$ such 
$$x^{n},y^{n+k},z^{n+3k},w^{n+5k}$$  be geometric sequence

> where   $x,y,z,w$ (be an   distrinct postive numbers) arithmetic progression.

for $n=k=1$, we have
$$\begin{cases}
(x+d)^4=x(x+2d)^4\\
(x+2d)^4=(x+d)^2(x+3d)^6
\end{cases}$$
where $y=x+d,z=x+2d,w=x+3d,d\neq 0$

since $$\dfrac{x+d}{x+2d}=\sqrt[4]{x}\Longrightarrow d=\dfrac{x(1-\sqrt[4]{x})}{2\sqrt[4]{x}-1}$$
taking in $(x+2d)^4=(x+d)^2(x+3d)^6$,we have 
$$(2x^{1/4}-1)^4=x^{9/2}(2-x^{1/4})^6$$
use computer only found $x=1$ is postive integer.then $d=0$

for other case,I can't solve

Comment: Yes, let $x=y=z=w=1$ which is arithmetic progression with $d=0$ and $n$ and $k$ be arbitrary integer, and you get geometric sequence with $q=1$. Can you say a little about your problem and your motivation?

Comment: @ShahroozJanbaz,$x,y,z,w$ be an distrinct postive integers.

Answer (score 2):

Really a comment, but too long:
$A,B,C,D$ is a geometric progression if and only if $B/A=C/B=D/C$, so in your case, you're trying to solve the two equations
$$ x^nz^{n+3k} = y^{2n+2k} \quad\hbox{and}\quad y^{n+k}w^{n+5k}=z^{2n+6k} $$
with the additional conditions that
$$ y=x+d,\quad z=x+2d,\quad w=x+3d. $$
So you have a pair of Diophantine equations in the four variables $(x,d,n,k)$.
What is the context for your problem? Did you just randomly make it up, or did it come up naturally when working on some other problem? What have your tried? Did you try some small values of $n$ and $k$? In particular, did you rule out at least the case $n=k=1$? Did you do a computer search that makes it plausible that there are no solutions?

Comment: Thank you, $d\neq 0$,I can't prove this diophantine equations no solutions.